# javascript enum is empty when posting to Laravel 5.2.*

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel-5

Hopefully this is an easy one, and as mentioned in the title the javascript enum that I'm setting is empty on the server.  Here is a watered down code snipped so you can experiment:

routes.php

```
Route::post('generalenquiries/send', 'CommsController@send');
```

layout.blade.php

```
<head>
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}" />
    ...
</head>
```

javascript code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });

    var EmailTypeEnum = {
        GENERAL_ENQUIRY: 0
        ,SELF_CATERING: 1
        ,REPORT_BUG: 2
        ,NEWSLETTER: 3
        ,properties: {
            0: {name: "GENERAL_ENQUIRY", value: 0, code: "GE"},
            1: {name: "SELF_CATERING", value: 1, code: "SC"},
            2: {name: "REPORT_BUG", value: 2, code: "RB"},
            3: {name: "NEWSLETTER", value: 3, code: "N"}
          }
    };

    $( "#general_enquiries_form" ).submit(function() {
        var form        = $( this ),
            action      = form.attr("action"),
            isValid     = form.valid(),
            valSum      = $(".validation-summary");

        var emailType = EmailTypeEnum.GENERAL_ENQUIRY;
        var emailTypeName = EmailTypeEnum.properties[emailType].name;   // emailTypeName == "GENERAL_ENQUIRY"

        if ( isValid ) {
            valSum.removeClass( "error" );
            valSum.addClass( "success" );
            valSum.html( "Sending message..." );

            var data = {
                message_type: emailTypeName
                ,first_name: first_name.val()
                ,last_name: last_name.val()
            };

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                // our data object
                url: action,        // the url where we want to POST
                data: data
            })
            // using the done promise callback
            .done(function(data) {
                // log data to the console so we can see
                console.log(data);

                // here we will handle errors and validation messages
                if ( data.success != true ) {
                    valSum.removeClass( "success" );
                    valSum.addClass( "error" );
                    valSum.html( data.message );
                } else {
                    valSum.removeClass( "error" );
                    valSum.addClass( "success" );
                    valSum.html( data.message );
                }
            })
            // using the fail promise callback
            .fail(function(data) {
                // show any errors
                // best to remove for production
                console.log(data);

                valSum.removeClass( "success" );
                valSum.addClass( "validation-summary error" );
                valSum.html( "Server Error: " + data.statusText + " processing your request." );
            });
        }
    });
});
```

CommsController.php

```
class CommsController extends Controller {
    public function send(Request $request) {
        try {
            // $request->input('message_type') returns empty but $request->input('first_name') displays the correct value.
            echo ($request->input('message_type') ." ". $request->input('first_name'));
            die();
        }
        catch(Exception $e) {
            $response = array (
                'success' => false,
                'message' => $e->getMessage(),
                $request
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I presume this is not the problem but it should be at least `echo ($request->input('message_type'));`

Comment: @fire Yeah you're correct, while debugging I forgot to include the apostrophes when calling $request->input.  As you stated that's not the problem though.

Comment: You must not be sending the data correctly, you haven't pasted the rest of your javascript. Use the developer toolbar in your browser to look at the AJAX request and make sure it's sending a POST request with `message_type=GENERAL_ENQUIRY` in the body.

Comment: @fire I'm definitely sending the data correctly as $request->input('first_name') is displaying the name I entered on the form, but for some reason $request->input('message_type').  I'll take a look at the developer tools to see what the issue could be as you suggested, and if I still can't find the problem I'll past the rest of my javascript.

Comment: @fire I've added more meat to give a better idea of the ajax call as well, so if you spot something I'm missing before I manage to find any problems when using the developer tools please let me know.

Comment: If `$request->input('first_name')` works then your definitely not sending `message_type` through correctly. Use the toolbar to figure it out.